# Symbol Table of a C program

Tags: c, memory, symbols

I'm having big trouble understanding how a symbol table works: my textbook describes how a compiler works, but never makes any symbol table example. The concepts of Scope and Linkage are also pretty confusing.

For instance, one assignment that is giving me trouble; given this C code:

```
extern int x;
const int z = 3;
static short int w;

void g( void ){
    static int t;
    ...
}
```

Assuming the memory is organized in the following parts: TEXT, RODATA (Read Only), DATA, BSS, SHARED, ...STACK, HEAP.

Compile a symbol table with the following fields:
Symbol, Size, Scope (Local or Global), Linkage (External or Internal), Address (Defined at creation or not), Segment (of memory).

I understand that a symbol can either be a function or a variable; but when I used the nm command on the object file I got this output:

```
00000000 T main
00000000 b w
00000000 R z
```

The g function and the int t aren't here at all!

The output should mean the following: main() is in the TEXT section, w is not initialized, z is read only. So, if I understand correctly, that should mean that main goes to TEXT, z to RODATA, w to BSS (Segment field).

My question is: why are g and t missing? How do I fill the other fields (or just a brief, practical description of the difference between SCOPE and LINKAGE is welcome)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols are Created only for Globally Declared variables. Not for Function and Variables Declared inside the Functions.

There are Two types of symbols.
1. Strong symbols
2. Weak Symbols

If the Globally declared variable is Initialized then it comes under the category of Strong symbols.
for example

```
const int z = 3;
```

If the Globally declared variable is Not initialized then it comes under the category of Weak symbols.
for example

```
static short int w;
```

Comment: Isn't this a question of linkage rather than scope? As I understand it (I may be wrong), symbols are needed for variables with external linkage only (and then it doesn't matter if they are declared at file scope or at block scope)? I mean, `w` isn't accessible from another translation unit.

Comment: It does not mean about accessing the variable's. but in general way it is.